# How to style a string result from C# displayed in HTML (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm having a problem figuring out **how to give style to a result** (string) of a database in C#, connected to ASP.NET. I'd like to have that my `row["Grens"]` has a different font-size than `row["Sanctie"]` for exemple.

I display the result in a simple div:

```
<div id="resultaat" runat="server"></div>
```

What I tried to do was *(this doesn't work)*:

```
public string ToonGrenzenPerZoekwoord(string zoekwoord)
    {
        string list ="";

        foreach (DataTable table in _persistcode.SearchGrenzenByKeyword("%" + zoekwoord + "%").Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                list += "<span class='t1'>" + row["Grens"].ToString() + ": "+"</span>" + "<span class='t2'>"+row["Sanctie"].ToString() + "<br>" + "Dit hoort thuis in de categorie: " + row["IDCategorieën"].ToString() + "</span>";
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

My **CSS** looks like this at the moment:

```
  .t1{
      font-size: 30px;
      color:white;
  }

  .t2{
      font-size: 18px; 
      color:white;
  }
```

Comment: Try inspect element and See what your span will be named in run time, then change your class name from t2 to that name. That's it.

Comment: @Stranger You mean that the class name could be changed to stuff like `$program_$module_t1` by the system? But a span created on the fly doesn't change its class name like that, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @MrLister just give it a test. If the class name is changed then you should change your class name, if not, you are right and maybe the problem is in another location!

Comment: There is no reason this would not work. Unless you overwrite `t1` and `t2` somewhere else.

Comment: you can change your class name from `t2` to `span[class*="t2"]` also.

Comment: @Stranger I did actually test the OP's source before I noticed your comment. But I am not the OP, so I can't see what his context is.

Comment: @MrLister controls which have a `runat=server` tag, usually change their IDs in run time and output and it may affect `css` classes or `javascript` codes.

Comment: Hi, I could show you the full context if that would help? @MrLister

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know @Stranger

Comment: There's an empty element.style{} tag there. t1 and t2 don't even appear. @Stranger

Comment: @LucasVerhoest use View Source and scroll to your target span and tell me what you see there, or even add a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 0):

*I can advise you some solutions:*

**1.** use Browser `inspect element` or `View Source` and See what your span will be named in run time, then change your class name from `t2` to that name.

**2.** use Browser `inspect element` or `View Source` and see what your parent div will be named then rename your `t2` class to something like this: `#div_resultaat_01 .span .t2`

**3.** use `Attribute` Selectors and change your `t2` class name to `span[class*="t2"]` which means any span which its class name contains `t2`.

**4.** use `nth child` selector to Select even or odd spans. for example you can edit your css like this:

```
.resultaat span:nth-child(odd){
             font-size: 30px;
             color:white;
        }
.resultaat span:nth-child(even){
             font-size: 18px; 
             color:white;
        }
```

see which one will work for you, most of times, I myself use *solution 1*.

Answer (score 0):

If you see your css is good but still not working, you can add the !important to your css attributes (for example: font-size: 30px !important;)